# "Asking for cache data failed" and "Assuming drive cache: write through" messages after that Ubuntu boot failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu, cache, runlevel

Today I was using my (old) Compaq laptop where Lubuntu is regularly installed on a partition. Suddenly, it stopped to respond to any inputs, so I (wrongly?) decided to restart the system.

After the logo Lubuntu had shown in the end of the booting process, the screen went black, the line

```
Stopping System V runlevel compatibility
```

showed and the two following messages

```
Asking for cache data failed
```

and

```
Assuming drive cache: write through
```

repeatedly appeared. My laptop was stuck there and the operating system did not start.

I have been looking for some advice on the Internet during this afternoon, especially here on askubuntu.com, but it seems sadly that nobody has encountered exactly the same type of error. I am still working on that. If you have any ideas, please reply to this post.

Many Thanks

Comment: I tried to restart again, both normal mode and recovery mode. Even by choosing "Previous Linux versions". I tried to do some checks by pressing "esc" at the beginning when the system starts and making some diagnostic procedures as proposed in the boot menu. The problem remained unchanged and my laptop was still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I managed to solve the problem:

1. First, I run a Lubuntu live cd and I chose the first option to run
   Lubuntu without installing it.
2. Then, I entered in the laptop Lubuntu partition where all folders and
   files are stored. I just saw that there were no more free
   space: the partition was completely full.
3. I tried to delete some useless files to clean the storage, but I
   discovered that when using a live cd you do not have root
   permissions to do that. However, I identified some files I could
   have deleted.
4. So I restart the system again and, when the error messages appeared,
   I reached the Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
5. There, after having entered both username and password of my Lubuntu
   installation, with the two basic command lines

   ```
   cd
   ```

   and

   ```
   dir
   ```

   I reached the files I wanted to delete;
6. and I purged them by using

   ```
   rm -f filename.extension
   ```

   command line.
7. In the end, I restarted the laptop once again and now the operating
   system works fine.

So the problem was "simply" that there was not sufficient free space in Lubuntu partition.

One question still remains: how is it possible that I run out of space? I am pretty sure that there was some GB of free space. I really do not understand: I didn't download anything nor I created any new files or documents before the laptop froze. Please write below if you have any suggestions.

I really hope other people with the same problem will find this answer helpful.

Comment: I do not know if this may help but, before Lubuntu completely froze, I had been working with Thunderbird to check my job emails. This was in fact a new task, that I have never done before from home.

Is it possible that Thunderbird was doing some sync with the job email account, downloading by default all the old emails to work off-line, so that space occupied (for example by cache files?) abruptly increased? 

How does sync work with Thunderbird?

Comment: That is likely the cause. Depending on your settings Thunderbird might have downloaded all email. You can find where your "profile folder" is in the Thunderbird settings and see how big it is.

Comment: Mine is in `/home/[user]/.thunderbird`